# Data Mapping and Submission with Next.js and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I try to understand how data is handled on submit in next.js and typescript.

I have for that made an modal, that works like a formwizzard. I successfully manage to get ordinary input fields data submitted, so that the id of the field will be made an field in my formsubmission, as I understand it.

Now, I have two react-datetime selects with timepicker next to eachother in a component, the idea is, that they works like open/closed hours. I furthermore have two inputs working as a 'Closed all day' and 'Open all day' selection. They need to add values in both inputs on select, and not being able to be chosen at the same time. No hocus pocus, but then again. My data does not go as smoothly to my formsubmission as my other fields, and I do not see why.

I hope someone could explain me where I go wrong. I do believe it's in the way I try to map the data, but I can't pinpoint exactly where.

I could fix it with chatgpt, but I would like to understand where I go wrong. So I hope for a little hint!

Right now my datastructure in my submission is perfect, but all strings are empty, despite chosen values.

AdModal.tsx component:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import useAdModal from "@/app/hooks/useAdModal";
import { FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import OpeningHours from "@/app/components/inputs/OpeningHours";

enum STEPS {
  OPENING_HOURS = 6,
}

const AdModal = () => {
  const adModal = useAdModal();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [step, setStep] = useState(STEPS.SERVICES);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      openHours: [
        { day: "Mon", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Tue", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Wed", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Thu", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Fri", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Sat", open: "", close: "" },
        { day: "Sun", open: "", close: "" },
      ],
    },
  });
  const openHours = watch("openHours");

  const setCustomValue = (id: string, value: any) => {
    setValue(id, value, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true,
    });
  };

  const updateOpeningHours = (
    day: string,
    formattedHours: { open: string; close: string }
  ) => {
    const dayIndex = openHours.findIndex(
      (item: { day: string }) => item.day === day
    );

    if (dayIndex !== -1) {
      setCustomValue(`openHours[${dayIndex}].open`, formattedHours.open);
      setCustomValue(`openHours[${dayIndex}].close`, formattedHours.close);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = async (data) => {
    if (step !== STEPS.PRICE) {
      return onNext();
    }

    const { openHours, ...restOfData } = data;

    console.log("Errors:", errors);
    console.log("Form Data:", data);

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await axios.post("/api/listings", data);
      toast.success("Your Ad Is Successfully Created!");
      router.refresh();
      reset();
      setStep(STEPS.SERVICES);
      adModal.onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something went wrong, unfortunately");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  if (step === STEPS.OPENING_HOURS) {
    bodyContent = (
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 max-h-[50vh] overflow-y-auto">
        <OpeningHours
          day="Monday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Tuesday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Wednesday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Thursday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Friday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Saturday"
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
        <hr />
        <OpeningHours
          day="Sunday "
          register={register}
          disabled={false}
          required={false}
          errors={errors}
          setCustomValue={setCustomValue}
          onUpdateOpeningHours={(day, formattedHours) =>
            updateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours)
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={adModal.isOpen}
      onClose={adModal.onClose}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      actionLabel={actionLabel}
      secondaryActionLabel={secondaryActionLabel}
      secondaryAction={step === STEPS.SERVICES ? undefined : onBack}
      title="Create a new ad!"
      body={bodyContent}
    />
  );
};

export default AdModal;
```

OpeningHours.tsx component:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TimePicker from "./TimePicker";
import TimeInput from "./TimeInput";
import { FieldErrors, UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";

interface OpeningHoursProps {
  day: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  required?: boolean;
  register: UseFormRegister<any>;
  errors: FieldErrors;
  setCustomValue: (id: string, value: any) => void;
  onUpdateOpeningHours: (
    day: string,
    formattedHours: { open: string; close: string }
  ) => void;
}

const OpeningHours: React.FC<OpeningHoursProps> = ({
  day,
  disabled,
  required,
  register,
  errors,
  onUpdateOpeningHours,
  setCustomValue,
}) => {
  const [openingTime, setOpeningTime] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [closingTime, setClosingTime] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [closedDay, setClosedDay] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [allDay, setAllDay] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isOpenPicker, setIsOpenPicker] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [formattedHours, setFormattedHours] = useState({
    open: "",
    close: "",
  });

  const getFormattedOpeningHours = (time: Date | null): string[] => {
    if (!time) {
      return ["", ""];
    }

    const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      hour12: true,
    };

    const formattedTime = time.toLocaleTimeString([], options);
    return formattedTime.split(" - ");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const formattedHours = {
      open: getFormattedOpeningHours(openingTime || new Date())[0],
      close: getFormattedOpeningHours(
        closingTime || openingTime || new Date()
      )[1],
    };

    setFormattedHours(formattedHours);
  }, [openingTime, closingTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onUpdateOpeningHours(day, formattedHours);
  }, [day, formattedHours, onUpdateOpeningHours]);

  const formatTime = (time: Date) => {
    const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      hour12: true,
    };

    return time.toLocaleTimeString([], options);
  };

  const handleTimeSelection = (newTime: Date | null, field: string) => {
    const updatedTime = newTime || new Date();

    if (field === "opening") {
      setOpeningTime(updatedTime);
      setCustomValue(`${day}.open`, formatTime(updatedTime));
    } else if (field === "closing") {
      setClosingTime(updatedTime);
      setCustomValue(`${day}.close`, formatTime(updatedTime));
    }
  };

  const handleCheckboxChange = (type: string) => {
    if (type === "allDay") {
      setAllDay(!allDay);
      setClosedDay(false);
      setOpeningTime(null);
      setClosingTime(null);
    } else if (type === "closed") {
      setClosedDay(!closedDay);
      setAllDay(false);
      setOpeningTime(null);
      setClosingTime(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-start w-full relative gap-4">
        <h3 className="font-semibold text-neutral-500 mt-2">{day}</h3>

        <div className="flex items-start gap-4">
          <TimeInput
            label="Opening at"
            disabled={allDay || closedDay || disabled}
            selectedTime={openingTime}
            onChange={(newTime) => handleTimeSelection(newTime, "opening")}
            required={required}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
            isClosed={closedDay}
            isAllDay={allDay}
          />

          <TimeInput
            label="Closing at"
            disabled={allDay || closedDay || disabled}
            selectedTime={closingTime}
            onChange={(newTime) => handleTimeSelection(newTime, "closing")}
            required={required}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
            isClosed={closedDay}
            isAllDay={allDay}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="text-neutral-700">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={allDay}
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange("allDay")}
          />
          <label className="ml-2">All day</label>
        </div>

        <div className="text-neutral-700">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={closedDay}
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange("closed")}
          />
          <label className="ml-2">Closed</label>
        </div>

        {isOpenPicker && (
          <TimePicker
            selectedTime={new Date()}
            onChange={(newTime) => handleTimeSelection(newTime || null)}
            onClose={() => setIsOpenPicker(false)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default OpeningHours;
```

TimeInput.tsx component:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import TimePicker from "./TimePicker";

interface TimeInputProps {
  label: string;
  type?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  selectedTime: Date | null;
  onChange: (newTime: Date | null) => void;
  isClosed: boolean;
  isAllDay: boolean;
}

const TimeInput: React.FC<TimeInputProps> = ({
  label,
  type = "text",
  disabled,
  selectedTime,
  onChange,
  isClosed,
  isAllDay,
}) => {
  const [isOpenPicker, setIsOpenPicker] = useState(false);

  const handleInputClick = () => {
    setIsOpenPicker(true);
  };

  const handleTimeSelection = (newTime: Date | null) => {
    onChange(newTime);
    setIsOpenPicker(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full relative">
      <input
        disabled={disabled}
        placeholder=" "
        type={type}
        onClick={handleInputClick}
        value={
          isAllDay
            ? "All Day"
            : isClosed
            ? "Closed"
            : selectedTime
            ? selectedTime.toISOString().split("T")[1].substring(0, 5)
            : ""
        }
        //value={}
        className="
          peer
          w-full
          p-4
          pt-6 
          font-light 
          bg-white 
          border-2
          rounded-md
          outline-none
          transition
          disabled:opacity-70
          disabled:cursor-not-allowed
          pl-4
          border-neutral-300
          focus:border-black
        "
      />
      <label
        className="
          absolute 
          text-md
          duration-150 
          transform 
          -translate-y-3 
          top-5 
          z-10 
          origin-[0] 
          left-4
          peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 
          peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 
          peer-focus:scale-75
          peer-focus:-translate-y-4
          text-zinc-400
        ">
        {label}
      </label>

      {isOpenPicker && (
        <TimePicker
          selectedTime={selectedTime || new Date()}
          onChange={handleTimeSelection}
          onClose={() => setIsOpenPicker(false)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeInput;
```

TimePicker.tsx component:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import daDK from "date-fns/locale/da";

registerLocale("da-DK", daDK);

interface TimePickerProps {
  selectedTime: Date;
  onChange: (time: Date | null) => void;
}

const TimePicker: React.FC<TimePickerProps> = ({ selectedTime, onChange }) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState<Date | null>(selectedTime);

  const handleTimeChange = (newTime: Date | null) => {
    if (newTime !== null) {
      // Copenhagen time zone offset in minutes (UTC+1 during CET)
      const copenhagenTimeZoneOffset = 60;

      const adjustedTime = new Date(
        newTime.getTime() + copenhagenTimeZoneOffset * 60000
      );

      setTime(adjustedTime);
      onChange(adjustedTime);
    } else {
      setTime(null);
      onChange(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={time}
      onChange={handleTimeChange}
      showTimeSelect
      showTimeSelectOnly
      timeIntervals={15}
      dateFormat="HH:mm"
      timeCaption="Time"
      popperPlacement="bottom"
      inline
    />
  );
};

export default TimePicker;
```